# Ending a table row in jstl

Tags: java, jstl

I'm trying to use a table to display some images, I'm allowed 3 images per row but I'm not sure how to end the table row when I have a row with less then 3 images.  See the snippet below for what I've been trying.

Using a `ul` I would not have to worry about it but I'm directed to use a table.  How can I make sure the last row is properly terminated ?  I'm newer to jstl.

Thanks,

```
    <% int endTRFlag = 0; %>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
      <core:forEach var="imageURL" items="${actionBean.imageURLs}" varStatus="rowCounter">
         <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#"><img src="${imageURL}" alt="Photo 1" class="img" /></a> 
          </div>
         </td>
         <% endTRFlag = 1; %>
      <core:if test="${ (rowCounter.count % 3 == 0) }">
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <% endTRFlag = 0; %>
      </core:if>
      <core:if test="${ (rowCounter.count % 3 != 0) && (endTRFlag == 0)}">
      </tr>
      </core:if>

      </core:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code below, I use `.index` instead of `.count` because it is 0-based, and so will work better for modulus (0/3, 3/3, etc.). `.last` is `true` if the current element is the last element in the list. This solution does cause validation errors in Eclipse (at least Ganymede), which is annoying.

```
<c:forEach var="imageURL" items="${actionBean.imageURLs}" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <c:if test="${rowCounter.index mod 3 eq 0}">
        <tr>
    </c:if>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <c:if test="${(rowCounter.index+1) mod 3 eq 0 or rowCounter.last}">
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the `</tr>` after the loop.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<c:set var="imageCnt" value="${fn:length(actionBean.imageURLs)}"/>
<table width="100%">  
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="imageURL" items="${actionBean.imageURLs}"
      varStatus="rowCounter">
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <span class="item"> 
          <a href="#"><img src="${imageURL}" alt="Photo 1" class="img" /></a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach begin="${imageCnt}" end="2">
      <td/>
    </c:forEach>
  </tr>  
</table>
```